# Easy mass ripping of CD's?

Tags: mp3, ripping, compact-disc

I have tens of CD's that I wish to rip (so to be able to listen to on my computer).

What (free) software (for PC, but also for Mac would be interesting) can help me get the most ripping in the least amount of time?

Requirements:

- Fast ripping of the CDs (not new)
- Many CD ripping mode.  e.g: I put a cd in, it rips it.  Once done, the CD is ejected.  I put a new one in, and the process repeats - with as little clicks needed from me. (this is the  main point for which I am hoping for some guidance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CDex](http://cdexos.sourceforge.net/) is your answer - download it, start it, set the directory where the songs will be placed (so you don't get them in Program Files) and under Options/Settings/CD Drive Settings/ click the option so it ejects the CD after ripping has been completed.

Simple, functional, just works.

The only thing is I don't know whether there is a Mac version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a program right off the top for the auto-eject. One thing that does strike me though is you should probably watch out for how old the CDs are - I'd be concerned with the data integrity. And if you're not too concerned for the integrity you might want to find a program that will at least automatically skip over bad files/sectors and continue copying such as TeraCopy.